# Python: Combine results of multiple pipelines

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

So, I am new to Python and I have been working on **Stanford NLP**. So, below are the two pipelines that I created.

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
doc = nlp('This is Prince Georges medic 829 were en route with a fourteen year old male, gunshot wound.  The patient has two wounds both, um, both approximately the same size.  )
for i, sent in enumerate(doc.sentences):
  print(f'====== Sentence {i+1} tokens =======')
  print(*[f'word: {word.text}\tupos: {word.upos}\txpos: {word.xpos}\tlemma: {word.lemma}\tdeprel: {word.deprel}' for word in sent.words], sep='\n')
```

**Sample Output Pipleine1:**

```
word: fourteen  upos: NUM   xpos: CD    lemma: fourteen deprel: nummod

word: year  upos: NOUN  xpos: NN    lemma: year deprel: obl:npmod

word: old   upos: ADJ   xpos: JJ    lemma: old  deprel: amod

word: male  upos: NOUN  xpos: NN    lemma: male deprel: nmod
```

```
nlp1 = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,ner')
doc1 = nlp1("This is Prince Georges medic 829 were en route with a fourteen year old male, gunshot wound.  The patient has two wounds both, um, both approximately the same size.)
#doc1 = nlp1("Prior to you with a 14 year old male, who got out of bed and had some sort of syncopal episode, and took a fall striking his head.")
print(*[f'token: {token.text}\tner: {token.ner}' for sent in doc1.sentences for token in sent.tokens], sep='\n')
```

**Sample Output Pipeline2:**

```
token: fourteen ner: B-DATE

token: year     ner: I-DATE

token: old      ner: E-DATE

token: male     ner: O
```

The first pipeline tags features like Part-of-Speech, does lemmatization, and dependency parsing (dependency relations between words). The second pipeline is for named entity recognition that returns the entity type.

I know how to dump the output of the two pipelines individually into a text/json format. What I want, is to combine the outputs of the two pipeline and then dump it into a text/json format. Is there a way that I can combine the outputs of multiple pipelines?

For example, if I combine, xpos, deprel, token and ner for "fourteen, year and old" it should return age as fourteen. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would recommend doing this is by changing the call to the second pipeline to use the document object that is returned from the first (you're `doc` variable).

the second code block would then be this instead:

```py
nlp1 = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,ner')
doc = nlp1(doc)
```

You can also pass in more than one doc at a time now as of version 1.2: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/pipeline.html#processing-multiple-documents

Also, if you have an arbitrary list of pipelines you want to apply in succession to a piece of text, you can do this:

```py
doc = None
for pipeline in pipelines:
    if doc:
        doc = pipeline(doc)
    else:
        doc = pipeline(text)
```